# Fourier transform for complex functions

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform

Supposing I have two integrable functions $f$ and $g$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to show that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat f(w)\space\overline{\hat g(w)}\ dw = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\space\overline{g(x)}\ dx$$

Where $\hat f(w)$ and $\hat g(w)$ are the respective Fourier transforms of the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I don't know where to start exactly. Should I let $f(x)=f_{1}(x)+if_{2}(x)$ and $g(x)=g_{1}(x)+ig_{2}(x)$ and go from there? Starting from the right-hand side of the equation hasn't let me anywhere so I'm guessing I have to compute the Fourier transforms of the respective functions.

Comment: What convention of Fourier Transform are you given ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik, $\hat f(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\space e^{-iwx}\space dx$

Comment: This is essentially Parseval's theorem. It is not an entirely trivial proof.

Comment: This is known as Plancherel's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(w)\overline{\hat{g}(w)}dw &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dw\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx' e^{-iw(x-x')}f(x)\overline{g(x')}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx'\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dw e^{-iw(x-x')}}_{=\delta(x-x')}f(x)\overline{g(x')}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx f(x)\overline{g(x)}
\end{align*}

If this property of the $\delta$ distribution is not known then it wil get a bit more complicated, which guess is what the non-triviality pointed out by copper.hat in the comments refers to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The $\delta$ distribution is known, but why is $\overline{\hat g(w)}$'s Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\overline{g(x)}e^{iwx}$, what happens to the minus sign in the exponential?

Comment: The complex conjugate of an integral (along the real line) is the integral of the complex conjugates and likewise the complex conjugate of a product is the product of the complex conjugates. We have
$\overline{\hat{g}(w)}=\overline{\int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x)e^{-iwx}dx}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \overline{g(x)e^{-iwx}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \overline{g(x)}\cdot\overline{e^{-iwx}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \overline{g(x)}e^{iwx}dx$.

If it is the $\overline{e^{-iwx}}=e^{iwx}$ step you have trouble with, note that $\overline{e^{-iwx}}=\overline{\cos(wx)-i\sin(wx)}=\cos(wx)+i\sin(wx)=e^{iwx}$